# How do I pass an API Token into Cookie via Python Request?

Tags: python-3.x, api, cookies, python-requests

I'm having issues w/ authenticating to pkgs.org api, a token was produced, by support mentioned it needs to be passed as a cookie. I've never worked with cookies before.

```
import requests
import json
import base64
import urllib3
import sys
import re
import os

token=('super-secret')


#s = requests.Session()
head = {'Accept':'application/json'}
r = requests.get('https://api.pkgs.org/v1/distributions', auth=(token), headers=head)


print(r)
print(r.connection)
print(r.cookies)
```

I tried to use the request.session method, to handle the cookie, but i honestly don't know syntax on how to ever 1 create a cookie, let alone pass the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the [API documentation](https://pkgs.org/api/) correctly you should set `acces_token` cookie:

```py
import requests


token = "super-secret"

cookies = {"access_token": token}
headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}

r = requests.get(
    "https://api.pkgs.org/v1/distributions", cookies=cookies, headers=headers
)
```

Comment: <Response [200]>